# Divide very large file into small ones following pattern

Tags: bash, awk, split, large-files

I have been working on this problem with only little success so I am coming here to get some fresh advices.

I am trying to extract the data of every scan into separate files.

The problem is that after 3196 files created I receive the error message : awk “makes too many open files”.

I understand that I need to close the files created by awk but I don't know how to do that.

Text inputfile is looking like this (up to 80 000 Scan):

```
Scan    1
11111    111
22222    221
...
Scan    2
11122    111
11122    111
...
Scan    3
11522    141
19922    141
...
```

For now I have been doing :

```
awk '/.*Scan.*/{n++}{print >"filescan" n }' inputfile
```

Which gives me an incremented output file for every Scan and crash after 3196 files created..

```
cat filescan1
Scan    1
11111    111
22222    221
...
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Perhaps `csplit` would be of interest to you - e.g. `csplit -f filescan -n 4 input.txt "/^Scan/" "{*}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [close the output file](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_39.html) as awk is keeping the file handle open.

```
awk '/.*Scan.*/{ 
  close(file);
  n++;
}
{ 
  file="filescan"n; 
  print >> file;
}' inputfile
```

Comment: Use ">>" to append as you keep closing the file and overwriting whats there. Or alternatively open and close the file in the same block as you increment n.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's expensive but you can eliminate file open/close at each line with `awk '/.*Scan.*/{close(file);n++}{...`

Comment: Thx all. So, awk '/.*Scan.*/{n++}{file="filescan"n;print >> file;close(file);}' inputfile   is doing the job but it is really slow...nearly 1sec per file created. Any idea to speed it up ? Thx anyway.

Comment: As karakfa mentioned, your usage should run quicker by only closing the file on increment as in the update

Comment: Indeed it is much faster ! I'll go with this option (as csplit is not installed on my unix machine @twalberg). Thx everyone.