# Too many open files error while running awk command

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I am trying to split a big file based on a pattern.
I am using awk command for this. After creating certain number of files it gives error: Too many open files.

Command is:

```
awk '/pattern here/{i++}{print > "file"i}' /input file
```

Can someone tell me how to close these files? I tried following but it gives error.

```
    awk '/pattern here/{i++}{print > "file"i}' /input file | close("file"i)
```

Comment: You need to run the `close` **in** awk not in a pipe on the output. Also you might want to look into `csplit` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Divide very large file into small ones following pattern (bash)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32228798/divide-very-large-file-into-small-ones-following-pattern-bash)

Comment: Related doc: [Close Files and Pipes](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Before starting on the next file, close the previous one:

```sh
    awk '/pattern here/{close("file"i); i++}{print > "file"i}' InputFile
```