# How to extract and put every blocks of text into loop statement

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, grep

I need to extract specific subsets of data in one file.
The file looks like below.

```
n_1
@ 1 #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   
*   #   #   #   #
*   #   #   #   #
*   #   #   #   #
*   #   #   #   #
*   #   #   #   #
#   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #
*   *   
*   *

n_2
@ 2 #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   
*   #   #   #   #
*   #   #   #   #
*   #   #   #   #
*   #   #   #   #
#   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #
*   *   
*   *

n_3
.
.
.
```

Here,

@ : a certain pattern

#: number

1,2,3 ... : index

* : character or string

n_i indicates the number of * between @ and # in each block. For example, we can say n_1 is 5 (between @ 1 # # ... and # # # # ...) and n_2 is 4, so there are no stationary lines for each block.

My final goal is to extract every block of test and insert them to loop statement on the termial. And then, re-extract data inside each block.

```
for i in $(extracted every block); do ...; done
```

Here, I found another way separate each block to each file.
`awk -vRS= '{print > "block" NR}' file`
But I encountered 
`awk: cannot open "block1021" for output (Too many open files)`
Because the file contains over 100,000 blocks

Comment: Not clear, please provide more clear details on your question.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Sorry for too many omissions. I add more details but it also quite difficult to understand my question. Please leave a comment when you are not understood. And another way means simply separate each paragraph to each file. But because of the massive number of paragraphs, I got that error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Too many open files error while running awk command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878146/too-many-open-files-error-while-running-awk-command)

Answer (score 1):

I solved my question anyway...

From https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052622/separate-log-text-according-to-paragraph

'Separate log text according to paragraph?'

`awk -vRS= '{print > "paragraph" NR}' log.txt`

From [Too many open files error while running awk command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878146/too-many-open-files-error-while-running-awk-command)

'Too many open files error while running awk command'

`awk '/pattern here/{close("file"i); i++}{print > "file"i}' InputFile`

I combined these two commands like,

`awk -vRS= '{close("block"i); i++}{print > "block"i}' file`

And it works. Thus, by inserting each separated file into the loop statement, I can some job on individual blocks. For example,

`for i in $(ls); do something; done`

Comment: `for i in $(ls)` takes lots of time for tremendous items.
So `for i in *` is recommended.