# AWK: cannot open "04477C9A875B80.csv" for output (Too many open files)

Tags: awk

I have a large CSV file and need to split it too multiple CSV files, using column 3 as the identifier and the resultant files will be named by the value in column 3

I am using the following:

```
awk -F ',' '{print > ($3".csv")}' playpass.csv
```

However I'm getting the error:

```
awk: cannot open "04477C9A875B80.csv" for output (Too many open files)
```

I know I need to close the files but after a few attempts, I'm getting nowhere and now back to a blank canvas

I tried the following with no luck as I get the same error

```
awk -F ',' '{close($1); i++}{print > $1}' query_result_2019-07-20T15_31_42.941Z.csv
```

Any advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Too many open files error while running awk command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878146/too-many-open-files-error-while-running-awk-command)

Comment: your field separator should be quoted separately from the rest of the awk program

Comment: Updated to use the example I'm referencing, get the same error

Comment: Your question is a bit vague to me: are there multiple rows with the same value in column 3 that you want in the same output file? Is column 3 sorted?  You haven't adapted the other answer to your problem -- the `i` is useless here

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to close the output file **before** you open it to write to it instead of after you've opened it. Change this:

```
'{close($1); i++}{print > $1}'
```

to this:

```
'{print > $1}{close($1); i++}'
```

There are other issues with your script of course but without sample input/output I don't want to make any suggestions.

Comment: Thanks - will try this but using gawk instead has sorted it

Comment: Using gawk works around it the error by handling the closures for you but if you didn't change your code like I showed or to remove the close() completely then it's bad code.