# How to convert date to unixtime when original is in dd-mm-yyyy format

Tags: date, awk

I am using the below to go through a CSV file and replacing all dates in the second column with the unixtime equivalent.

```
gawk -F',' -v OFS=','  '$2 {cmd="date -d \""$2"\" +%s"; cmd | getline $2; close(cmd)} 1' C.csv > D.csv
```

However all I am getting is this:

```
date: invalid date ‘21-07-2019 13:08’
date: invalid date ‘21-07-2019 14:59’
date: invalid date ‘20-07-2019 13:03’
date: invalid date ‘20-07-2019 14:44’
date: invalid date ‘20-07-2019 15:19’
date: invalid date ‘20-07-2019 13:36’
date: invalid date ‘21-07-2019 11:37’
date: invalid date ‘20-07-2019 14:51’
```

The date is valid - why isn't it being recognised as such?

It works for:

```
date -d '07/22/2019 11:37'
```

Another issue is that this column has mixed date types i.e. it has the above and some in the format `2019-07-18T14:15:00.000+02:00`

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure? If I run `date -d '21-07-2019 13:08'` I get the same error.

Comment: Yeah, I get an error...

Comment: You can try `awk -v FS=, -v OFS=, '{cmd = "date -d \""$2"\" \"+%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p\""}{ cmd|getline D; close(cmd); $2=D}1' C.csv`

Comment: Sorry, I updated question to say there are mixed data types in there

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output for us to be able to help you. Also [your response when I answered your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57126553/awk-cannot-open-04477c9a875b80-csv-for-output-too-many-open-files#comment100780547_57130044) was `using gawk instead has sorted it` so you should be using gawks builtin time functions not spawning a shell once per input line to call `date`. Please don't wait til you get an answer using `date` and then reject it too because you again solved it using gawk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have mixed date formats, it's mandatory that you convert the `dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM` format into `mm-dd-yyyy HH:MM`, you can try with this:

/* date.awk */

```
{
    if($2 ~ / /) {
        split($2,datetime, / /)
        dt = date[1]
        split(dt, dts, /-/)
        $2 = dts[2]"-"dts[1]"-"dts[3]" "date[2]
    }
}
{cmd = "date -d \""$2"\" \"+%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p\""}{ cmd|getline D; close(cmd); $2=D}1
```

Then,

```
awk -v FS=, -v OFS=, -f date.awk C.csv
```

should get you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making use of GNU awk, you can use its [time functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
     { timestring=$2":00"; gsub(/[-:]/," ",timestring);
       $2=mktime(timestring)
     }1' file
```

Be advised that this will convert to unixtime based on your local time-zone. Unix time is in UTC and your local time-zone might have daylight saving corrections. If the times in your file are in a given time-zone, eg. *Europe/Monaco*. Then you should do the conversion in exactly the same timezone.

```
$ TZ='Europe/Monaco' awk '{...}' file
```